# HTMLControl Style.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a web site created using C# and Visual Studio.

I have the following menu in my Site.master:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li runat="server" id="liHome">   <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="liAbout">  <a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
    <li runat="server" id="liContact"><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I have the following css:

```
.menu ul {}
.menu ul li a{padding:9px 10px; display:block; color:#fff; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}
.menu ul li a:hover{color:#00ff00; text-decoration:none; }
```

What I want to do is when the menu is clicked, I want the text of the selected menu item to change and stay a different colour.  In my Site.master.cs I am doing the following for the 'About' menu item for example:

```
    if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("About") == true)
    {   
        liContact.Style.Add("color", "#00ff00");
    }
```

But the colour does not stay green.  Can anyoe help me as to what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What does liContact refer to in your js code? Also, when is it applied?

Comment: You're asking if the request url contains "About" but then applying the style to li **contact**...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it should say "Contact" MyBad :(  liContact does not refer to anything in my js code.

Comment: If I did the following:liContact.Style.Add("border-top", "3px #7bc002 solid"); then a border will get added successfully to the top of the menu selection, so I'm wondering why the color of the text wont change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as follows

```
  if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("About") == true)
  {    
      liContact.Style.Add("color", "#00ff00!important");
  }
```

You need to add `!important` in your `css` only then it will work.
Otherwise it will override by the class.

### Edit 1

Other wise make a different class

```
.menu ul {}
.menu ul li a{padding:9px 10px; display:block; color:#fff; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}
.menu ul li a:hover{color:#00ff00; text-decoration:none; }

.menu ul li.selected a{padding:9px 10px; display:block; color:#00ff00; font-size:16px; 
       font-weight:bold;}
```

And rather then setting color replace the class.

```
liContact.Attributes.Remove("class");   
liContact.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");
```

### Edit 2

```
 .menu ul li.selected a:hover{padding:9px 10px; display:block; color:#00ff00; font-size:16px; 
       font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: The !important does not work. If I try your second method (Remove and add the class) then I find that this only works if I remove my original hover css class.  The hover class must be affecting it somehow.  But I want it to both hover green and then stay green. Hmmm. Thanks

Comment: @Harry you can create hover for the same class also. See my edits.

Comment: Shekhar, with this change now I find that initially the hover doesn't change color, but when the menu item is selected, it does not stay the selected color but hovering over it will change it to green.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood, I have now added in all the classes above and it now works (My original hover class, plus your two new classes). Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

[Active Html Link tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

this tutorial help you to solve your probloem.

By default, links will appear as follows in all browsers:

An unvisited link is underlined and blue
A visited link is underlined and purple
An active link is underlined and red